# Trying to create a stored procedure to insert data into postresql database - how to automatically enter primary key?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure to insert data into a table in a PostgreSQL 13 database.  How do I automatically enter the primary key?

Here is how I made the table

```
CREATE TABLE public.testing_serial
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('testing_serial_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    age integer,
    CONSTRAINT testing_serial_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Here is my attempted at a stored procedure and calling it

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_input("name" character varying,
                                        "age" integer)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
INSERT INTO testing_serial VALUES ("name","age");
$$;

CALL test_input('Cheese',2000);
```

I got the following error and surmise that SQL is expecting an input for the "id" column.  Is that correct?  How can I automatically generate the ID during input?

ERROR:  column "id" is of type integer but expression is of type character varying

LINE 5: INSERT INTO testing_serial VALUES ("name","age");
^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
SQL state: 42804
Character: 145

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to specify the column list with the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO testing_serial (name, age) VALUES ("name","age");
```

Comment: That was it, thank you - also I need to use single brackets around 'cheese' in the call